# .htaccess / mod-rewrite code to match results

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a question with regards to mod-rewrite.
I am re-building a site from a wordpress blog into a custom CMS.

They currently have blog posts which are XX.com/this-is-my-post. Problem is they also have pages which are: xx.com/contact-us

I have built my content pages (IE: xx.com/why-us) and used the following in the htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ content.php?c=$1 [L]
```

I did 301 redirects to anticipate blog posts and created them as xx.com/blog/this-is-my-post - but they do not want this.

So, how can I create something like the following:

If searching

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ content.php?c=$1 [L]
```

brings up no matches - move to the article/blog page to see if there is a match there:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ article.php?c=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way for the rewrite engine to know that loading the content at `content.php?c=$1` will or will not yield any matches for `$1`. Your best bet may be to route everything through a custom script that determines whether to include `content.php` or `article.php` depending on what `c` is, and use a rewrite rule and route everything through that.